# Keep tkinter menu open even when I close the terminal that pops up

Tags: python, tkinter, terminal

I have an exe file that is converted from a py script using pyinstaller. When I run this exe script, it opens a terminal then after a second opens my tkinter GUI, is there a way I can make it so when I close the terminal, it won't close the tkinter GUI? I would also want the terminal to be closed instantly. What I want is basically; after I run the exe file, only the tkinter GUI is remaining.

Comment: I know that if you use the file extension `*.pyw` instead of `*.py`, the Python interpreter will run your script without the console (i.e., no terminal window). Perhaps you could save your main Python script as a `*.pyw` instead of `*.py` and then try building the executable with Pyinstaller again to see if it still pops up the console...I suspect that it won't since the script that the `*.exe` is based on doesn't.

Comment: @JRiggles Thank you for this, however do you know how to manually open the terminal? I also would like to have the terminal for printing errors BEFORE the tkinter gui opens(sorry for not saying this last time)

Comment: I'm not sure I know a way to do that, unfortunately. The terminal window that opens is tied to the current Python interpreter session; that is, the thing that's currently running your tkinter app...closing that terminal window necessarily closes the app. I think the best you can do is hide it in the manner I described, *or* minimize the terminal window instead of closing it.